# Belongs to pivot table in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Let's say I'm having the following database schema:

[image]

`dogs` and `owners` are connected with classic `belongsToMany`. How about the `walks` table? I'd like to be able to use Eloquent goodies in such kind of relationship:

```
$dogs = Dog::with('walks')->get();
$walks = Walk::with('dogs')->get();
```

In theory, I could replace `dog_owner_id` with two separate columns: `dog_id` and `owner_id`. That would make it easy to use Eloquent, but I'd lose some data integrity, because unrelated Dog and Owner could potentially go for a walk (and that's not safe for neither!).

In *Walk.php*, how should the relations be defined?

```
public function dog() {
    // return ???;
}
```

How about *Dog.php* and *Owner.php*?

```
public function walks() {
    // return ???;
}
```

Comment: I believe you're looking for [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). I may be waaay off since it's been quite some time since I've done anything laravel related.

Comment: I think hasManyThrough is valid for Dog.php and Owner.php, but not sure about Walk.php.

Comment: I suppose you could just use old fashion joins if nothing else. Have a look [here](https://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-hasmanythrough-with-many-to-many)

Comment: I had a sort of similar expierence in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720436/how-to-get-multiple-joined-data-in-one-laravel-db-function but I believe there is nothing standard in eloquent to fix this. I would love to see such a thing though if it exists.

Comment: If that's your real structure, then `walks` seems odd to be related to the pivot table. It IS pivot table of sort - `owner + dog = walk`, isn't it?

Comment: Cześć :) this is not real structure. But even if it was, I don’t think it’s weird. Pivot could be used for example to validate if the dog can be taken for a walk by that particular person. Then, I could want to use foreign key with ondelete cascade, so any walks associated with forgotten dog-owner pair would also be gone.

Answer (score 8):

1- create 4 Models (Walk,Dog,Owner,DogOwner)

2- in Walk.php model

```
    public function dog()
{

    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        'App\Models\Dog',
        'App\Models\DogOwner',
        'id', // Local key on dog_owner table...
        'id', // Local key on dogs table...
        'dog_owner_id', // Foreign key on walks table...
        'dog_id' // Foreign key on dog_owner table...
    );
}

public function owner()
{

    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        'App\Models\Owner',
        'App\Models\DogOwner',
        'id', // Local key on dog_owner table...
        'id', // Local key on owners table...
        'dog_owner_id', // Foreign key on walks table...
        'owner_id' // Foreign key on dog_owner table...
    );
}
```

3- in Dog.php model

```
   public function walks()
    {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\Walk',
        'App\Models\DogOwner',
        'dog_id', // Foreign key on dog_owner table...
        'dog_owner_id', // Foreign key on walks table...
        'id', // Local key on dogs table...
        'id' // Local key on dog_owner table...
    );
    }
```

4- in Owner.php model

```
   public function walks()
   {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\Walk',
        'App\Models\DogOwner',
        'owner_id', // Foreign key on dog_owner table...
        'dog_owner_id', // Foreign key on walks table...
        'id', // Local key on owners table...
        'id' // Local key on dog_owner table...
    );
   }
```

Comment: Well, it's easier to achieve now when we have `PivotModel` in Laravel. I do it another way these days though, today I'd just put `dog_id` and `owner_id` to the `walks` table.

Comment: the pivot table works fine when the Relationship many to many for example (authors , posts , author_post )
 but here in walk table the relationship is one to one through pivot table 
and  in (dog,owner) table one to many through pivot table

Comment: I believe this may help. It did solve my problem. https://laravel.io/forum/12-28-2014-belongsto-relationship-with-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

As other have mentioned you can use HasManyThrough for this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Like you said this is valid for your Dog and Owner models. For your Walk model it is a little bit different but you have the nice option of mapping the query yourself:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
    'App\Post',
    'App\User',
    'country_id', // Foreign key on users table...
    'user_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
    'id', // Local key on countries table...
    'id' // Local key on users table...
);
```

Comment: Are you sure? Each walk has only one dog and one owner (at least in my world here :P).

Comment: Sure, so you define 2 methods.

Comment: I mean, `hasManyThrough` is designed to query for multiple records, not one.

Comment: I sincerely doubt there is a `standard way` in eloquent to get this done.

Comment: And also, in this case I will need to make a fake model based on the pivot, something like `DogOwnerPair`.

Comment: I tested it and it works fine that way: `return $this->hasManyThrough(Walk::class, DogOwnerPair::class, 'dog_id', 'dog_owner_id');` in the `Dog` class. Making it work for `Walk` is harder part though.